# Position a JQuery Dialog over another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am showing a JQuery dialog on a button click (add to cart button). The JQuery dialog shows the message 'x item(s) added to cart' and auto closes in y seconds. I want to display the dialog exactly on the add to cart button. The add to cart becomes visible only after the dialog box auto closes. How would I do it?

Comment: Please read before posting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - You need to include code and/or show some sort of attempt to solve the problem before asking for help.

Comment: @Keerthi, are you using jQuery UI? Can you show us your HTML/JS/CSS code regarding the add to cart button and the dialog please?

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/o92sjf08/7 The dialog opens in the center. I would want to position the dialog right over the add to cart button. I tried appendTo : '#addtocart', but that doesn't help

Comment: @TylerRoper Here is a screencast of what I am trying to acheive http://screencast.com/t/EyZqIOi4PD .

Comment: @Keerthi check my answer.

Comment: @Keerthi Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `position` to the following:

```
$dialog.dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: false,
  position: {
      my: 'left top',      //The point on the dialog box
      at: 'left top',      //The point on the target element
      of: $('#addtocart')  //The target element
  },
  draggable: true,
  width: '40%'
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/o92sjf08/11/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. This is a responsive page. So the width of the button would vary based on the device it is on (desktop view, tablet view and mobile view). Can I set the width of the Dialog to match the width of target item?

Comment: Try changing `width: 40%` to `width: $('#addtocart').width()`

Comment: I have something to add on...
I have a list of items on a webpage. 

Prod img     Prd name       Add to cart button
Prod img     Prd name       Add to cart button.. and on


The id for the button is 'addtobag_<prdid>' but the class is the same 'addtobag'. In the above example I have a page with four items listed. I click the button on the third item. The JQuery dialog should be positioned on top of the add to cart button on the third line. 

I need to find the id closest to the class addtobag and position the dialog box over that button. I'm unable to do it.